# cannot be resolved or not in a field

Tags: java, android

OK I'm new to android dev's and Java so I'm having problems with on click method here's my code Ii know I've gotta be close thanks in advance all I want my button to do is when its clicked on the phone play a sound.
But I get this error, pistol1 cannot be resolved or not in a field, it's a sound file that I want to play when I click on button.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pistol1);
        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

Comment: did you put pistol1 inside raw folder?

Comment: tried refreshing the project?

Comment: What kind of file is pistol1?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Comment: It's Mp3 file and yes it's inside raw folder. Refreshing didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your file is inside a folder called **raw** inside **res** folder ?

If so, did you made the good import ?

> import my.project.name.R

or

> import my.project.name.R.raw

Comment: Yes, your project_package_name.R.raw;

Comment: typically you import the R.class not raw

Comment: Yes it is inside of raw folder in Res

Answer (score 0):

As documentation is saying: [Android doc.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer)

> Here is an example of how to play audio that's available as a local
>   raw resource (saved in your application's res/raw/ directory):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
```

> In this case, a "raw" resource is a file that the system does not try
>   to parse in any particular way. However, the content of this resource
>   should not be raw audio. It should be a properly encoded and formatted
>   media file in one of the supported formats.

Also you should look over the: [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: It's Mp3 file which is supported by Android.